# ld: duplicate symbol _dbg_char

Tags: c, macos, libtool

Getting a linker error on osx (no errors on linux or fbsd for the same code):

```
ld: duplicate symbol _dbg_char in .libs/liboekernel_la-OEK_get.o and .libs/liboekernel_la-OEK.o
```

the 2 libs listed in the error are mine but the symbol isn't. c++flint confirms '_dbg_char' is in both libs but I'm not sure how to find where it comes from.

tricks, strategies, outright answers for how to id _dbg_char would be greatly appreciated.

project is using libtool/autotools and gcc 4.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a logging / debug macro that was defining dbg_char by '`dbg_ ## t`'.  fix was to make it static.  lessons learned:

1. osx adds a leading _ to symbol names.  it wasn't until i ran nm on linux and saw the same symbol without the leading _ that i thought to search the codebase for "`dbg_`" instead of "`_dbg_`"
2. osx was right to complain
3. rich irony that cut-and-pasting a debug macro i didn't fully understand caused me so much trouble

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if both libs `#include` a header file that declare `_dbg_char` but miss the `extern` keyword. Maybe that's `#ifdef` 'ed out for other platforms so you only hit that problem on OS X.

Comment: thanks.  i've run find with grep against the whole fs and have not found any _dbg_char in my nor apples *.h files.  still digging...